# Consumer(s)-Producer issue in webserver streaming an array of data

Tags: java, concurrency, producer-consumer, java.util.concurrent

[Producer-Consumer blog post](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2012/02/producer-consumer-design-pattern-with.html) states that:

> "2) Producer doesn't need to know about who is consumer or how many consumers are there. Same is true with Consumer."

My **problem** is that I have an array of data that I need to get from the Webserver to clients as soon as possible. The clients can appear mid-calculation. Multiple clients at different times can request the array of data. Once the calculation is complete it is cached and then it can simply be read.

**Exmaple Use Case**: While the calculation is occurring I want to serve each and every datum of the array as soon as possible. I can't use a BlockingQueue because say if a second client starts to request the array while the first one has already used .take() on the first half of the array. Then the second client missed half the data! I need a BlockingQueue where you don't have to take(), but you could instead just read(int index).

**Solution?** I have a good amount of writes on my array, so I wouldn't want to use CopyOnWriteArrayList? The Vector class should work but would be inefficient?
Is it preferable to use a ThreadSafeList like [this](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/util/concurrent/locks-concurrent/readwritelock/java-readwritelock-example/) and just add a waitForElement() function? I just don't want to reinvent the wheel and I prefer crowd tested solutions for multi-threaded problems...

Comment: How 2nd client (or any client) would know from which index it should read? Is there such thing as "consistent state of whole array" or any array element can be written and read independently?

Comment: All clients just start from the beginning, they need the whole array

Comment: I do have a library doing exactly that; but it uses its own async data source interface.

Comment: One more question: is it "write-once" array? Or data can be refreshed by producers?

Comment: It is a write-once array

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand you need to `broadcast` data to `subscribers/clients`. 
Here are some ways that I know for approaching it.

- Pure Java solution, every client has a `BlockingQueue` and every time you broadcast a message you put it every queue.

  ```
  for(BlockingQueue client: clients){
    client.put(msg);
  }
  ```
- [RxJava](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava) provides a [reactive approach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reactive_programming). Clients will be `subscribers` and ever time you `emit` a message, subscribers will be notified and they can choose to cancel their subscription

  ```
  Observable<String> observable = Observable.create(sub->{
      String[] msgs = {"msg1","msg2","msg3"};
      for (String msg : msgs) {
          if(!sub.isUnsubscribed()){
              sub.onNext(msg);
          }
      }
      if (!sub.isUnsubscribed()) { // completes
          sub.onCompleted();
      }

  });
  ```

  Now multiple subscribers can choose to receive messages.

  ```
  observable.subscribe(System.out::println);
  observable.subscribe(System.out::println);
  ```

  Observables are a bit `functional`, they can choose what they need.

  ```
  observable.filter(msg-> msg.equals("msg2")).map(String::length)
     .subscribe(msgLength->{
      System.out.println(msgLength); // or do something useful
  });
  ```
- [Akka](http://akka.io/) provides [broadcast routers](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/java/routing.html#Broadcast_Messages)

Comment: I like this solution, but unfortunately I did not specify that I do not know all my clients up front. If I am doing a long calculation, a new client can appear and request the data (starting at the beginning and then waiting for the result to be served).

Would I be able to have that new client catch up by broadcasting to an extra dummy array that just get copied to the new user as soon as it appears?

Comment: @smuggledPancakes of course, with RxJava you don't know who are the subscribers, it is dynamic if you will

Answer (score 0):

This is not exactly a trivial problem; but not too hard to solve either.

Assuming your producer is an imperative program; it generates data chunk by chunk, adding each chunk to the cache; the process terminates either successfully or with an error.

The cache should have this interface for the produce to push data in it

```
public class Cache

    public void add(byte[] bytes)

    public void finish(boolean error)
```

Each consumer obtains a new view from the cache; the view is a blocking data source

```
public class Cache

    public View newView()

public class View

    // return null for EOF
    public byte[] read() throws Exception
```

Here's a straightforward implementation

```
public class Cache
{
    final Object lock = new Object();

    int state = INIT;
    static final int INIT=0, DONE=1, ERROR=2;

    ArrayList<byte[]> list = new ArrayList<>();


    public void add(byte[] bytes)
    {
        synchronized (lock)
        {
            list.add(bytes);
            lock.notifyAll();
        }
    }

    public void finish(boolean error)
    {
        synchronized (lock)
        {
            state = error? ERROR : DONE;
            lock.notifyAll();
        }
    }


    public View newView()
    {
        return new View();
    }

    public class View
    {
        int index;

        // return null for EOF
        public byte[] read() throws Exception
        {
            synchronized (lock)
            {
                while(state==INIT && index==list.size())
                    lock.wait();

                if(state==ERROR)
                    throw new Exception();

                if(index<list.size())
                    return list.get(index++);

                assert state==DONE && index==list.size();
                return null;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

It can be optimized a little; most importantly, after state=DONE, consumers should not need `synchronized`; a simple volatile read is enough, which can be achieved by a `volatile state`

Comment: why wait/notifyall in 2015? why not Lock and Condition?

Comment: why yes? :) are they faster, do they make code look better? :)

Comment: they definitely make the code  look better, according to @BrianGoetz at least :)